# Обновление ListView привязанного к ArrayList - проблема

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, update

Использую:

`ListView` с `ArrayAdapter`, в который передаю `ArrayList<MyList>`.

`MyList` - мой класс, содержит другие списки, и поле `имя`. Отображается в списке как поле `Имя`.

Есть активность, которая может создавать список, или же изменять существующий (только `имя`, это и есть проблема).

При создании нового элемента - всё окей, элемент создаётся, `notifyDataSetChanged()` срабатывает, список обновляется.

При изменении элемента `ArrayList`, а конкретно при смене имени объекта `MyList` и применении того же `notifyDataSetChanged()` - ничего не происходит.

Создание списка:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyList>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MainActivity.list);
    listViewListLists.setAdapter(adapter);
    listViewListLists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("fromlistlists to List", MainActivity.list.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Кусок кода, в котором в зависимости от наличия переданного объекта (т.е. если передаём объект - подразумеваем изменение существующего, передаётся вроде нормально т.к. активность создания списка заполняется нужными данными объекта) или создаётся новый объект или редактируется существующий.

Новый создаётся правильно.

```
if (!name.equals("")) {
    if (MyListAddActivity.isEdit) {                       
        MyListAddActivity.listToEdit.setName(name);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), MyListAddActivity.listToEdit.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        new MyList(name);
    }
    FragmentListLists.refreshAdapter();
```

*Toast* с *getName* отображается правильно.

Как обновить вид списка не при добавлении элемента, а при редактировании?

Comment: А что у вас за обращения к полям и методам `MainActivity` через указание класса? Это в той же активити где код или это из фрагмента или из другой активити?

Comment: Это из другой активити.

Comment: Данный способ является плохой практикой, так как активити, не находящаяся на переднем плане в любой момент может быть уничтожена и ваше приложение упадет. Для взаимодействия между активити используйте интенты с методом `setResult()`,локальные бродкасты и другие инструменты, но не такое взаимодействие.

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему тем, что передал в метод меняющий элемент номер позиции в списке и изменение списка

```
adapter.getItem(position).setName;
adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
```

заработало.